# Flutter - Exception caught by widget library

Tags: android, flutter, widget

I keep getting an exception caught by widget library error. My app still loads and functions perfectly, but this error keeps red screening my app for a fraction of a second then loads my app normally.

I have no idea and have tried a few different things with the code to modify it as well as google. I haven't found anything on the internet with this sort of issue. It technically still works, thats why I am confused.

```
Performing hot restart...
Syncing files to device SM A505YN...
Restarted application in 2,533ms.
D/AndroidAudioRecorder( 1091): handleHasPermission true
I/flutter ( 1091): ══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY WIDGETS LIBRARY ╞═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
I/flutter ( 1091): The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown building AudioButton(dirty, state:
I/flutter ( 1091): AudioButtonState#41f3c):
I/flutter ( 1091): The getter 'duration' was called on null.
I/flutter ( 1091): Receiver: null
I/flutter ( 1091): Tried calling: duration
I/flutter ( 1091): 
I/flutter ( 1091): The relevant error-causing widget was:
I/flutter ( 1091):   AudioButton file:///C:/Users/lukem/Documents/FlutterProjects/mimir_app/lib/pages/home.dart:20:13
I/flutter ( 1091): 
I/flutter ( 1091): When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
I/flutter ( 1091): #0      Object.noSuchMethod (dart:core-patch/object_patch.dart:51:5)
I/flutter ( 1091): #1      AudioButtonState.build (package:mimirapp/pages/audio/AudioButton.dart:123:25)
I/flutter ( 1091): #2      StatefulElement.build (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4663:28)
I/flutter ( 1091): #3      ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4546:15)
I/flutter ( 1091): #4      StatefulElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4719:11)
I/flutter ( 1091): #5      Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4262:5)
I/flutter ( 1091): #6      ComponentElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4525:5)
I/flutter ( 1091): #7      StatefulElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4710:11)
I/flutter ( 1091): #8      ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4520:5)
I/flutter ( 1091): ...     Normal element mounting (19 frames)
I/flutter ( 1091): #27     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3490:14)
I/flutter ( 1091): #28     MultiChildRenderObjectElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5991:32)
I/flutter ( 1091): ...     Normal element mounting (210 frames)
I/flutter ( 1091): #238    Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3490:14)
I/flutter ( 1091): #239    MultiChildRenderObjectElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5991:32)
I/flutter ( 1091): ...     Normal element mounting (267 frames)
I/flutter ( 1091): #506    Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3490:14)
I/flutter ( 1091): #507    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3258:18)
I/flutter ( 1091): #508    RenderObjectToWidgetElement._rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:1174:16)
I/flutter ( 1091): #509    RenderObjectToWidgetElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:1145:5)
I/flutter ( 1091): #510    RenderObjectToWidgetAdapter.attachToRenderTree.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:1087:17)
I/flutter ( 1091): #511    BuildOwner.buildScope (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2620:19)
I/flutter ( 1091): #512    RenderObjectToWidgetAdapter.attachToRenderTree (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:1086:13)
I/flutter ( 1091): #513    WidgetsBinding.attachRootWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:927:7)
I/flutter ( 1091): #514    WidgetsBinding.scheduleAttachRootWidget.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:908:7)
I/flutter ( 1091): (elided 11 frames from class _RawReceivePortImpl, class _Timer, dart:async, and dart:async-patch)
I/flutter ( 1091): 
I/flutter ( 1091): ════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
I/flutter ( 1091): Instance of 'Recording'
I/flutter ( 1091): RecordingStatus.Initialized
```

I have a main.dart file that accesses my Home widget, that brings the audiobutton into my body. The classes are shown below.

Home File:

```
class _HomeState extends State<Home> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Mimir'),
        centerTitle: true,
        backgroundColor: Colors.green[300],
      ),
      body: AudioButton(),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {
          print("help is on it's way");
          showHelpDialog(context);
        },
        child: Icon(Icons.help),
        backgroundColor: Colors.green[400],
      ),
      //bottomNavigationBar - used for navigating to new pages
    );
  }
}
```

AudioButton

```
class AudioButton extends StatefulWidget {
  final LocalFileSystem localFileSystem;

  AudioButton({localFileSystem})
      : this.localFileSystem = localFileSystem ?? LocalFileSystem();

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => new AudioButtonState();
}

class AudioButtonState extends State<AudioButton> {
  List buttonPadding = [30.0,10.0,30.0,10.0];
  double buttonFontSize = 16.0;
  FlutterAudioRecorder _recorder;
  Recording _current;
  RecordingStatus _currentStatus = RecordingStatus.Unset;
  int length_recording = 120;

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    _init();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: <Widget>[
        Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
          children: <Widget>[
            //Init/record button
            RaisedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                switch (_currentStatus) {
                  case RecordingStatus.Initialized:
                    {
                      _start();
                      break;
                    }
//                  case RecordingStatus.Recording:
//                    {
//                      _pause();
//                      break;
//                    }
//                  case RecordingStatus.Paused:
//                    {
//                      _resume();
//                      break;
//                    }
                  case RecordingStatus.Stopped:
                    {
                      _init();
                      break;
                    }
                  default:
                    break;
                }
              },
              child: _buildText(_currentStatus),
              padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(buttonPadding[0],buttonPadding[1],buttonPadding[2],buttonPadding[3]),
              elevation: 5.0,
              color: Colors.green[500],
              splashColor: Colors.green[200],
            ),
            //Stop button
            RaisedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                //t.cancel();
                _stop();
              },
              child: Text(
                  "Stop",
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    fontSize: buttonFontSize,
                    color: Colors.white,
                    letterSpacing: 1.0,
                  )
              ),
              padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(buttonPadding[0],buttonPadding[1],buttonPadding[2],buttonPadding[3]),
              elevation: 5.0,
              color: Colors.green[500],
              splashColor: Colors.green[200],
            ),
            //play button
            RaisedButton(
              onPressed: onPlayAudio,
              child: Text(
                  "Play",
                  style: TextStyle(
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  fontSize: buttonFontSize,
                  color: Colors.white,
                  letterSpacing: 1.0,
                  )
              ),
              padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(buttonPadding[0],buttonPadding[1],buttonPadding[2],buttonPadding[3]),
              elevation: 5.0,
              color: Colors.green[500],
              splashColor: Colors.green[200],
            ),
          ],
        ),
        SizedBox(
          height: 20.0,
        ),
        //timer text variable
        new Text(
            "${_current.duration.inSeconds.toString()}",
            style: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 60.0,
            ),
        ),
        //anything that helps to debug eg recording status
        SizedBox(
          height: 50.0,
        ),
        new Text("Status : $_currentStatus"),
      ],
    );
  }

  _init() async {
    try {
      if (await FlutterAudioRecorder.hasPermissions) {
        String customPath = '/flutter_audio_recorder_';
        io.Directory appDocDirectory;
//        io.Directory appDocDirectory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
        if (io.Platform.isIOS) {
          appDocDirectory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
        } else {
          appDocDirectory = await getExternalStorageDirectory();
        }

        // can add extension like ".mp4" ".wav" ".m4a" ".aac"
        customPath = appDocDirectory.path +
            customPath +
            DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch.toString();

        // .wav <---> AudioFormat.WAV
        // .mp4 .m4a .aac <---> AudioFormat.AAC
        // AudioFormat is optional, if given value, will overwrite path extension when there is conflicts.
        _recorder =
            FlutterAudioRecorder(customPath, audioFormat: AudioFormat.WAV);

        await _recorder.initialized;
        // after initialization
        var current = await _recorder.current(channel: 0);
        print(current);
        // should be "Initialized", if all working fine
        setState(() {
          _current = current;
          _currentStatus = current.status;
          print(_currentStatus);
        });
      } else {
        Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(
            new SnackBar(content: new Text("You must accept permissions")));
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
  }

  _start() async {
    try {
      int count = 0;
      await _recorder.start();
      var recording = await _recorder.current(channel: 0);
      setState(() {
        _current = recording;
      });

      const tick = const Duration(seconds: 1);
      new Timer.periodic(tick, (Timer t) async {
        count++;
        if (_currentStatus == RecordingStatus.Stopped) {
          t.cancel();
        }

//        if (count > length_recording) {
//          t.cancel();
//          _stop();
//        }
        var current = await _recorder.current(channel: 0);
        // print(current.status);
        setState(() {
          _current = current;
          _currentStatus = _current.status;
        });
      });
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
  }

  _resume() async {
    await _recorder.resume();
    setState(() {});
  }

  _pause() async {
    await _recorder.pause();
    setState(() {});
  }

  _stop() async {
    var result = await _recorder.stop();
    print("Stop recording: ${result.path}");
    print("Stop recording: ${result.duration}");
    File file = widget.localFileSystem.file(result.path);
    print("File length: ${await file.length()}");
    setState(() {
      _current = result;
      _currentStatus = _current.status;
    });
  }

  onPlayAudio() async {
    AudioPlayer audioPlayer = AudioPlayer();
    await audioPlayer.play(_current.path, isLocal: true);
  }

  Widget _buildText(RecordingStatus status) {
    var text = "";
    switch (_currentStatus) {
      case RecordingStatus.Initialized:
        {
          text = 'Start';
          break;
        }
      case RecordingStatus.Recording:
        {
          text = 'Recording';
          break;
        }
      case RecordingStatus.Paused:
        {
          text = 'Resume';
          break;
        }
      case RecordingStatus.Stopped:
        {
          text = 'Reset';
          break;
        }
      default:
        break;
    }
    return Text(text,
        style: TextStyle(
            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
            fontSize: buttonFontSize,
            color: Colors.white,
            letterSpacing: 1.0,
        ));
  }
```

Comment: Please provide snippet of your code. Obviously from error there is null in variable `duration` so you can't work with that variable before assigning but without code, we can't help you much.

Comment: Hey, sorry I added the code in for the two relevant classes. I have gone throguh it but can't seem to figure out where the error is coming from.

Answer (score 0):

`NoSuchMethodError` with "X was called on null" usually occurs when the variable where the method was called may have yet to be initialized. It's likely thrown when `_current.duration.inSeconds.toString()` was called. Make sure that `Recording _current;` has been initialized before fetching the property.